# Adding a comment hides parts of earlier comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, editor

The comments are all show correctly. Then I hit the add comment button then the existing comments are reformatted and the last few characters are hidden under the right hand sidebar

I am Safari 7.0.1  on OSX 10.9.1

e.g. on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589983/saxparser-escaping-special-characters)
[image]

Comment: Doesn't happen for me (Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m).

Comment: I just tested this on my MacBook and cannot repro on the same Safari and OSX versions.  Here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sob4.png

Comment: @NickCraver Try Zooming in - laso I zoom text only

Comment: @Mark we don't support text-only zoom, if you are zooming *some* parts of the page and not others - expect things to break. We do support zooming the entire page in or out at least one level, that's perfectly reasonable.