# Why and when does the comment overflows to the text on the right side?

Tags: bug, comments

I noticed that the comments after a certain length overflows to the right side and makes the test illegible. Is it because of the browser or for some other reason?

I went through the following link

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86988/comment-formatting-issue-text-overflows-to-the-right-frame

which led me to

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84099/text-running-over-other-text-on-so-comments

which I found is deleted and does not exist. So what is the way out?

The screenshot:(As requested by Mosa)
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Apparently, the way out is to blame Firefox for this.

Comment: The deleted post was for Firefox 3.x and 4 beta only. Those versions are no longer supported anyway.

Comment: So, are you saying this problem cannot be solved?

Comment: I had this as well with Safari see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219799/adding-a-comment-hides-parts-of-earlier-comments)

Comment: @Adarsh where have you noticed that? Can you add a link to post/comment + screenshot please? A question is not a bug report...

Comment: I see you have a whole lot of browser extensions -- does this also happend when you disable them?

Comment: Yes.. It does..